# Python multithreading list append gives unexpected results

Tags: python, multithreading, list

I want to test if it's ok to append to list from two threads, but I'm getting messy output:

```
import threading


class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, alist):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.alist = alist

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        append_to_list(self.alist, 2)
        print "Exiting " + self.name
        print self.alist


def append_to_list(alist, counter):
    while counter:
        alist.append(alist[-1]+1)
        counter -= 1

alist = [1, 2]
# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread("Thread-1", alist)
thread2 = myThread("Thread-2", alist)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
print alist
```

So the output is:

```
Starting Thread-1
Exiting Thread-1
 Starting Thread-2
 Exiting Main Thread
Exiting Thread-2
[1[1, 2[, 1, 2, 23, , 34, 5, 6, ]4
, 5, , 3, 64, 5, ]6]
```

Why it's so messy and alist not equal to [1,2,3,4,5,6]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: @kroltan got me to thinking some more, and i think your example is in fact more threadsafe then i originally thought. The issue is not in the multiple writer threads in total, it's specifically in this line:

> alist.append(alist[-1]+1)

There's no guarantee that the `append` will happen directly after the `alist[-1]` completes, other operations may be interleaved.

With a detailed explanation here:
http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm

> Operations that replace other objects may invoke those other objects’ **del** method when their reference count reaches zero, and that can affect things. This is especially true for the mass updates to dictionaries and lists. When in doubt, use a mutex!

Original Answer:

> This is undefined behavior, as you have multiple threads writing to
>   the same bit of memory - hence the "messy" output your observing.
>
> > I want to test if it's ok to append to list from two threads, but I'm getting messy output
> >
> > I think you've successfully tested this, and the answer is No.
> >     Lots of more detailed explanations on SO:
> >     https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943027/62032

Comment: Is it truly undefined? Lists are certainly thread-safe. It is certainly *unpredictable* to concurrently write to stdout, but definedly defined.

Comment: Lists are thread safe. Your first statement is correct  - the list numers won't grow monotonically due to other operations getting in between retrieving )alist[-1] and the call to `append`. But the "messy" output is due tto the print statement: that one is ot thread safe, and the output of both calls to print bis mangled. The resulting ist should still contain only int objects, though.

Answer (score 7):

**Summary**

Why is the output messy?

==> Because a thread may yield part way through executing a `print` statement

Why is `aList` not equal to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]?

==> Because the content of `aList` may change between reading from it and appending 
to it.

**Output**

The output is messy because it is being produced by python2's `print` statement 
from within threads, and the `print` statement is not [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029816/how-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-print-in-python-2-6).  This means 
that a thread may yield while `print` is executing.  In the code in the 
question there multiple threads printing, so one thread may yield while 
printing, the other thread may start printing and then yield so producing the 
interleaved output seen by the OP.  IO operations such as writing to `stdout` 
are very slow in CPU terms, so it's quite likely that the operating system may 
pause a thread performing IO because thread is waiting on the hardware to do 
something.

For example, this code:

```
import threading


def printer():
    for i in range(2):
        print ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']


def main():
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=printer) for x in xrange(2)]
    for t in threads: 
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

produces this interleaved output:

```
>>> main()
['foo', 'bar'['foo', , 'bar', 'baz']
'baz']
['foo', ['foo', 'bar''bar', 'baz']
, 'baz']
```

The interleaving behaviour can be prevented by using a `lock`:

```
def printer():
    for i in range(2):
        with lock:
            print ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']


def main():
    global lock
    lock = threading.Lock()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=printer) for x in xrange(2)]
    for t in threads: 
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

>>> main()
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

**The contents of the list**

The final content of `aList` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` if the statement

`aList.append(aList[-1] + 1)`

is executed atomically, that is without the current thread yielding to another 
thread which is also reading from and appending to `aList`.

However this not how threads work.  A thread may yield after reading 
the last element from `aList` or incrementing the value, so it is quite 
possible to have a sequence of event like this:

1. Thread1 reads the value `2` from `aList`
2. Thread1 yields
3. Thread2 reads the value `2` from `aList`, then appends `3`
4. Thread2 reads the value `3` from `aList`, then appends `4`
5. Thread2 yields
6. Thread1 appends `3`
7. Thread1 reads the value `3` from `aList`, then appends `4`

This leaves `aList` as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4]`

As with the `print` statements, this can be prevented by making threads acquire a `lock` before executing `aList.append(aList[-1] + 1)`

(Note that the `list.append` method *is* [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe) in pure python code, so there is no risk that the value being appended could be corrupted.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same variable to read and write, it would have an undefined behavior, I executed the code and got 2 different outputs on two different instances on the same machine:

```
Starting Thread-1 
Exiting Thread-1 
[1, 2, 3, 4]Starting Thread-2   

Exiting Main Thread 
 [Exiting Thread-21, 2, 3, 4 
, [51, , 62],
3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and this

```
Starting Thread-1
Exiting Thread-1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Exiting Main Thread
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Starting Thread-2
Exiting Thread-2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You should use synchronize to get the output as desired or else wait for the undetermined state to get you correct output

**EDIT:** You can go through this article about how to implement synchronize http://theorangeduck.com/page/synchronized-python

Comment: Ok, appretiate your answer, but can you please provide some code that implements synchronizing?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the threading.lock method to ensure that while actions (such as printing output to screen) are performed by one thread they don't interfere with the action of other threads.